# Image animation on Android

Tags: android

I want an image on an Android screen to appear smaller when the user touches down on it and to get back to its original size when the user releases it. I want the animation to be smooth and I also want to utilize minimum computing resources. How can this best be implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code

```
          @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                   // do something here when touch
                break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                   // do something here when touch release     
                break;
                }

                return true;
            }
```

for animation try this [**animation-source_code**](http://rehman-furniture.com/attaullahcs/stackdir/AndroidAnimationsUsingXML.zip)

Comment: Nailed. Deserves best answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably use the `ScaleAnimation` with the `onTouch` event of the view. In onTouch when you get the `ACTION_DOWN` you can start the `ScaleAnimation` and when you get `ACTION_UP` just revert the animation.